# (PythonCrashCourse) Alien Invasion Ship Movement

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

My problem with the code is that the ship's movement is strange; sometimes when I press the left or right arrow key it doesn't move the correct way. Or, the ship doesn't move at all. In this project I have the modules alien.py, alien_invasion.py, bullet.py, button.py, gamefunctions.py, game_stats.py, scoreboard.py, settings.py, and ship.py. However, I will only provide the most relevant ones.

ship.py:

```
    import pygame
    class Ship():
         def __init__(self, screen, ai_settings):
              self.screen = screen
              self.ai_settings = ai_settings
              self.image = pygame.image.load('images/spaceship.png')
              self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
              self.screen_rect = screen.get_rect()
              self.rect.centerx = self.screen_rect.centerx
              self.rect.bottom = self.screen_rect.bottom
              self.center = float(self.rect.centerx)
              self.moving_right = False
              self.moving_left = False

          def update(self):
              if self.moving_right and self.rect.right < self.screen_rect.right:
                  self.center += self.ai_settings.ship_speed_factor
              if self.moving_left and self.rect.left > 0:
                  self.center -= self.ai_settings.ship_speed_factor
                  self.rect.centerx = self.center

          def blitme(self):
               self.screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)

          def center_ship(self):
              self.center = self.screen_rect.centerx
```

game_functions.py:

```
    import sys
    import pygame
    from bullet import Bullet
    from alien import Alien
    from time import sleep
         def check_keydown_events(event, ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets):
              if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                   ship.moving_right = True
              elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                   ship.moving_left = True
              elif event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                   fire_bullet(ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets)
              
         def check_keyup_events(event, ship):
               if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    ship.moving_right = False
               elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    ship.moving_left = False

          def check_events(ai_settings, screen, stats, play_button, ship, aliens, bullets):
               for event in pygame.event.get():
                    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                         sys.exit()
                    elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                         check_keydown_events(event, ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets)
                    elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                         check_keyup_events(event, ship)
```

alien_invasion.py:

```
    import sys
    import pygame
    import game_functions as gf
    from settings import Settings
    from ship import Ship
    from pygame.sprite import Group

    def run_game():
         pygame.init()
         ai_settings = Settings()
         screen = pygame.display.set_mode((ai_settings.screen_width, ai_settings.screen_height))
         screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1200, 650))
         pygame.display.set_caption("Alien Invasion")
         while True:
             gf.check_events(ai_settings, screen, stats, play_button, ship, aliens, bullets)
             if stats.game_active:
                  ship.update()
                  gf.update_bullets(ai_settings, screen, stats, sb, ship, aliens, bullets)
                  gf.update_aliens(ai_settings, stats, screen, ship, aliens, bullets)
             gf.update_screen(ai_settings, screen, stats, sb, ship, aliens, bullets, play_button)
             for event in pygame.event.get():
                  if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                       sys.exit()
             screen.fill(ai_settings.bg_color)
             ship.blitme()
             screen.fill(bg_color)

      run_game()
```

Comment: If someone presses the K_RIGHT key and holds it down for a second, how many keydown events will that trigger?  One, or more than one?

Comment: You shouldn't loop over `pygame.event.get()` in multiple places, the loop that just checks for the `QUIT` event in your main loop is probably processing and throwing away the events you are interested in.

Comment: @IainShelvington I deleted the pygame.event.get() in the main loop, and now the movements work! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by multiple calls to `pygame.event.get()`.

[`pygame.event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get) get all the messages and remove them from the queue[`pygame.event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get) get all the messages and remove them from the queue. See the documentation:

> This will get all the messages and remove them from the queue. [...]

If `pygame.event.get()` is called in multiple event loops, only one loop receives the events, but never all loops receive all events. As a result, some events appear to be missed.

Get the events once and use them in multiple loops or pass the list or events to functions and methods where they are handled:

```py
def check_events(event_list, ai_settings, screen, stats, play_button, ship, aliens, bullets):
    
    for event in event_list:

        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            check_keydown_events(event, ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets)
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            check_keyup_events(event, ship)
```

```py
def run_game():
    # [...]

    while True:
    
        event_list = pygame.event.get()

        gf.check_events(event_list, ai_settings, screen, stats, play_button, ship, aliens, bullets)
         
        # [...]
             
        for event in event_list :
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()
       
        # [...]
```